# Code architecture - Flask - Where to put form validation from database?

Tags: validation, flask, architecture, wtforms, web-architecture

I'm wondering where should I put a validation form which accessing database.
Basically I will need user to enter `item_type` and I want to check first i the `item_type` has exist in database.

There are 3 options:

1. In the database model, I have `ItemType` class and I put function `add()` which will check if existing item has exist or not
2. In view, so in the route of the page, from wtforms `form.validate_on_submit()`, I do a check to get data from database, and if exist I will put error in here
3. In wtforms `validate()`, adding extra validation after default validation of the `Form` class

I've seen people using number 2 and 3, but not sure which one is the best. The error message that I want will also need to display it on the specific field of the form (this is achieveable by method 2 and 3 since they have reference to the form field) but then again since it is related to accessing database, maybe it is better to put everything regarding database access to model functions?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, if it comes from a form then it should be validated on that form and then raise an error for that specific field when invalid. See the example bellow:

```
class SigninForm(Form):
    """Form for signin"""
    email = StringField('Email',
                        validators=[
                            DataRequired("Email shouldn't be empty."),
                            Email('Email format is not correct.')
                        ])

    password = PasswordField('Password',
                             validators=[DataRequired("Password shouldn't be empty.")])

    def validate_email(self, field):
        """ 
            verify if account exists and if not raise an error in
            that field. 
        """
        user = User.query.filter(User.email == self.email.data).first()
        if not user:
            raise ValueError("Account doesn't exist.")

    def validate_password(self, field):
        """ 
            Verify if password is valid and if not raise an error in
            that field. 
        """
        if self.email.data:
            user = User.query.filter(User.email == self.email.data).first()
            if not user or not user.check_password(self.password.data):
                raise ValueError('Password is not correct.')
            else:
                self.user = user
```

The view function for this example:

```
@app.route('/signin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signin():
    """Signin"""
    form = SigninForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # sign in function to register user into a session
        signin_user(form.user)
        return redirect(url_for('site.index'))
    return render_template('account/signin/signin.html', form=form)
```

Comment: If you're not passing `validate_email` and `validate_password` into each respective Field constructor as custom validators, how/when are they being called? Is there something auto-magically happening as a result of your method naming plus inheriting the WTForm Form?